# how can i query all records in mysql where field is not empty or null?

Tags: mysql

how can i query all records in mysql where field is not empty or null?

such as bellow, some products_name is empty ,and some is null , how to get other has values records?
[image]

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `a`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a`;
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `products_name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of a
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('1', 'hello');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('2', '222');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('3', null);
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('4', '');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('5', '5555');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do:

```
SELECT * FROM `a` WHERE `products_name` IS NOT NULL AND `products_name` != '';
```

Comment: Try to use **`IFNULL`**

Comment: Why would you need IFNULL? He wants to get the records where the name is NOT NULL and not empty isnt it? In case he wants all records but wants to do something else with the NULL fields he could use IFNULL. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: ***how can i query all records in mysql where field is not empty or null?***

Comment: Just change the AND Constraint in the query i posted above to an OR constraint.

Answer (score 3):

You can express it succinctly as:

```
SELECT * FROM a
WHERE ifnull(products_name, '') != ''
```